# Build a flush 1x2 piston door in Minecraft Bedrock Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to build a flush piston door in Minecraft Bedrock Edition. I have two sticky pistons stacked on top of each other that are facing right, two more sticky pistons facing toward the player that are connected to the right-facing pistons. A block of choice is placed in front of the front-facing pistons. However, when I activate the first set of pistons, the blocks no longer are attached to the sticky pistons. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: It would be helpful for you to post a screenshot so we can see what's going on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't quite yet have a screenshot, my visualization skills lead me to thinking you have something like this:
[image: Your Original Setup]
If you want to move the iron blocks, you will need to add more pistons:
[image: The Better Setup]
And now the wiring: This can get a bit tricky, so study the images carefully!
[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 4]
And this is what it will look like!
[image: Final Image]

Comment: Yes, that is perfect! However, can you put a top-down screenshot of the completed circuitry? Thanks!

Comment: @fasterthanlight A picture has now been added. Thanks for trying out my answer!